# Driving an optoisolator with a 2N2222?

Tags: bjt, opto-isolator

I'm driving an opto-isolated MOSFET gate driver with a 2n2222 transistor from a 3.3V microcontroller (TI Tiva C, 2-8mA max per pin). The IX3108G that I selected needs 10-16mA to be driven ON.

This is the circuit I created to do this, but the optoisolator just stays ON and never gets turned off: https://imgur.com/H4l0Q7R

Am I doing something wrong in the circuit, or is it more likely that I have a wiring mistake or bad chip?

Comment: Know the beta value of transistor and the solve so that the transistor acts as a switch.

Comment: It should work, so you probably have a wiring error or faulty component. I you have a multimeter then set PWM to 0% and measure voltages across all components.

Comment: Try reducing the 2N2222 base resistor to 1k.

Comment: @froggy, Can you post your source code?